# OctoberCMS Controller Soft Delete

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

Does OctoberCMS have a soft deleting form/list behavior? As per now, I had to implement the **restore** button myself, I also had to implement the *list* filtering myself. Are there any available package/plugin/sample code (preferably recommended implementation) of this feature?

What I have done:

- Create an ajax controller for `onRestore`.
- Add `filter` in list config.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, For soft deletion **no** there is no plugins, for restoration you need to make it `by your self` and it seems **you already made it , so far good**.

To `show records` which are `deleted` you need this code in your `controller` but may be you are already added that code. just for information I am adding it here.

```
public function listExtendQuery($query)
{
    $query->withTrashed();
}

public function formExtendQuery($query)
{
    $query->withTrashed();
}
```

**And filters** , well for them there is **no** plugin as well :( , which can help to `build filter`.

> but seems in future they can add them in builder plugin (may be)

for filters there is `doc` https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#filter-text , you can use **type text filter** to `filter particular column` based on `text search`. for this you need to use `latest October-CMS build`.

you can refer this functionality from here
https://github.com/octobercms/october/pull/3094

> **config_filter.yaml**

```
scopes:
    id:
        label: ID
        type: text
        conditions: id = :value
        size: 2

    username:
        label: Username
        type: text
        conditions: username = :value
```

Also if you want to check code you can check it which filters are available for now.
https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/widgets/Filter.php

sorry, but it seems currently no plugins are there which can help you for soft-delete and filters (according to my knowledge).

Comment: yes kind of sad, But we expect some cool new features in future from rainLab plugin builder :)